# Does http CONNECT method get proxy relay data at TCP level?

Tags: http, nginx, https, tcp

This is the question about HTTP CONNECT method.

I learned that after CONNECT request from client a TCP connection is established between proxy and remote server.

Then, **at the step of SSL handshake**, does the proxy evaluate and relay any http data from client up to at TCP level? So the data is not passed to application level of the proxy?

I understood that after SSL session establishment any data from client is encrypted and the proxy cannot read those. But how about the time before SSL session establishment, that is, SSL handshake step?

Comment: The data is typically HTTPS so the proxy can't see it anyway. It should just copy the bytes.

Comment: @user207421
Yes I agree that. But what I mean is **the time before https session is established** between client and remote server, that is, **SSL handshake step**. At SSL handshake step before https session establishment, the proxy may be able to see the data from the client. Is it possible? Or impossible because of TCP level relay?

Comment: It is not possible to send any data over any TLS connection before the handshake is complete, proxy or no proxy. If that doesn't answer your question I don't know what does.

Answer (score 2):

After the proxy has sent a successful response to the clients CONNECT request a normal proxy will forward all data between client and server without any changes. This includes the TLS handshake for HTTPS connections tunneled using CONNECT.

Note that there are proxies which do SSL interception (typically at firewalls). In this case the data are not blindly forwarded but the proxy will be an **active** man in the middle which means that the client does not receive the original certificate from the server and that the proxy will decrypt and maybe even modify the traffic between client and server.